# How Do I Skip The Header Names or Columns on CSV Upload

Tags: php, mysql

On my csv upload script, the header or Column name data contained in the csv file is always going to be the same, however is pretty messed up with duplicates, spaces, slashes, pound signs, hyphens etc, etc. The order of the columns is also always going to be the same.

Whenever I use the upload script using one of these csv files I get no error, and nothing really happens, no data makes it to the db. However if I change the headers or column names everything works fine. Meaning I have to format the headers (Column Names) of the csv file and remove all the spaces, special characters etc and everything seems ok.

Is there a way to just add the data from the csv file without the header or column names getting in the way?

Here is what I am using:

```
    <?php

 include '_inc/include.php';
 if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) {

//get the csv file
$file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name];
$handle = fopen($file,"r");
fgets($handle);

//loop through the csv file and insert into database
do {
    if ($data[0]) {
        $mysql_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO extrusiondata_01 (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5, COL6, COL7, COL8, COL9, COL10, COL11, COL12, COL13, COL14, COL15, COL16, COL17, COL18, COL19, COL20, COL21, COL22, COL23, COL24, COL25, COL26, COL27, COL28, COL29, COL30, COL31, COL32, COL33, COL34, COL35, COL36, COL37, COL38, COL39, COL40, COL41, COL42, COL43, COL44, COL45, COL46, COL47, COL48, COL49, COL50, COL51, COL52, COL53, COL54, COL55, COL56, COL57, COL58, COL59, COL60, COL61, COL62, COL63, COL64, COL65, COL66, COL67, COL68, COL69, COL70, COL71, COL72, COL73, COL74, COL75, COL76, COL77, COL78, COL79, COL80, COL81, COL82, COL83, COL84, COL85, COL86, COL87, COL88, COL89, COL90, COL91, COL92, COL93, COL94, COL95, COL96, COL97, COL98, COL99, COL100, COL101, COL102, COL103, COL104, COL105, COL106, COL107, COL108, COL109, COL110, COL111, COL112, COL113, COL114, COL115, COL116, COL117, COL118, COL119, COL120, COL121, COL122, COL123, COL124, COL125, COL126) VALUES
            (
                '".addslashes($data[0])."',
                '".addslashes($data[1])."',
                '".addslashes($data[2])."',
                '".addslashes($data[3])."',
                '".addslashes($data[4])."',
                '".addslashes($data[5])."',
                '".addslashes($data[6])."',
                '".addslashes($data[7])."',
                '".addslashes($data[8])."',
                '".addslashes($data[9])."',
                '".addslashes($data[10])."',
                '".addslashes($data[11])."',
                '".addslashes($data[12])."',
                '".addslashes($data[13])."',
                '".addslashes($data[14])."',
                '".addslashes($data[15])."',
                '".addslashes($data[16])."',
                '".addslashes($data[17])."',
                '".addslashes($data[18])."',
                '".addslashes($data[19])."',
                '".addslashes($data[20])."',
                '".addslashes($data[21])."',
                '".addslashes($data[22])."',
                '".addslashes($data[23])."',
                '".addslashes($data[24])."',
                '".addslashes($data[25])."',
                '".addslashes($data[26])."',
                '".addslashes($data[27])."',
                '".addslashes($data[28])."',
                '".addslashes($data[29])."',
                '".addslashes($data[30])."',
                '".addslashes($data[31])."',
                '".addslashes($data[32])."',
                '".addslashes($data[33])."',
                '".addslashes($data[34])."',
                '".addslashes($data[35])."',
                '".addslashes($data[36])."',
                '".addslashes($data[37])."',
                '".addslashes($data[38])."',
                '".addslashes($data[39])."',
                '".addslashes($data[40])."',
                '".addslashes($data[41])."',
                '".addslashes($data[42])."',
                '".addslashes($data[43])."',
                '".addslashes($data[44])."',
                '".addslashes($data[45])."',
                '".addslashes($data[46])."',
                '".addslashes($data[47])."',
                '".addslashes($data[48])."',
                '".addslashes($data[49])."',
                '".addslashes($data[50])."',
                '".addslashes($data[51])."',
                '".addslashes($data[52])."',
                '".addslashes($data[53])."',
                '".addslashes($data[54])."',
                '".addslashes($data[55])."',
                '".addslashes($data[56])."',
                '".addslashes($data[57])."',
                '".addslashes($data[58])."',
                '".addslashes($data[59])."',
                '".addslashes($data[60])."',
                '".addslashes($data[61])."',
                '".addslashes($data[62])."',
                '".addslashes($data[63])."',
                '".addslashes($data[64])."',
                '".addslashes($data[65])."',
                '".addslashes($data[66])."',
                '".addslashes($data[67])."',
                '".addslashes($data[68])."',
                '".addslashes($data[69])."',
                '".addslashes($data[70])."',
                '".addslashes($data[71])."',
                '".addslashes($data[72])."',
                '".addslashes($data[73])."',
                '".addslashes($data[74])."',
                '".addslashes($data[75])."',
                '".addslashes($data[76])."',
                '".addslashes($data[77])."',
                '".addslashes($data[78])."',
                '".addslashes($data[79])."',
                '".addslashes($data[80])."',
                '".addslashes($data[81])."',
                '".addslashes($data[82])."',
                '".addslashes($data[83])."',
                '".addslashes($data[84])."',
                '".addslashes($data[85])."',
                '".addslashes($data[86])."',
                '".addslashes($data[87])."',
                '".addslashes($data[88])."',
                '".addslashes($data[89])."',
                '".addslashes($data[90])."',
                '".addslashes($data[91])."',
                '".addslashes($data[92])."',
                '".addslashes($data[93])."',
                '".addslashes($data[94])."',
                '".addslashes($data[95])."',
                '".addslashes($data[96])."',
                '".addslashes($data[97])."',
                '".addslashes($data[98])."',
                '".addslashes($data[99])."',
                '".addslashes($data[100])."',
                '".addslashes($data[101])."',
                '".addslashes($data[102])."',
                '".addslashes($data[103])."',
                '".addslashes($data[104])."',
                '".addslashes($data[105])."',
                '".addslashes($data[106])."',
                '".addslashes($data[107])."',
                '".addslashes($data[108])."',
                '".addslashes($data[109])."',
                '".addslashes($data[110])."',
                '".addslashes($data[111])."',
                '".addslashes($data[112])."',
                '".addslashes($data[113])."',
                '".addslashes($data[114])."',
                '".addslashes($data[115])."',
                '".addslashes($data[116])."',
                '".addslashes($data[117])."',
                '".addslashes($data[118])."',
                '".addslashes($data[119])."',
                '".addslashes($data[120])."',
                '".addslashes($data[121])."',
                '".addslashes($data[122])."',
                '".addslashes($data[123])."',
                '".addslashes($data[124])."',
                '".addslashes($data[125])."'
            )
        ");
    }
} while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,100000,",","'"));
//

//redirect


}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Import a CSV File with PHP & MySQL</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php if (!empty($_GET[success])) { echo "<b>Your file has been imported by import 55.</b><br><br>"; } //generic success notice ?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
  Choose your file: <br />
  <input name="csv" type="file" id="csv" />
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
    <P> Display Data Contents <a href ='Data-Display-test.php'>here</a></P>
</body>
</html>
```

I understand this may not be the best in terms of sql injections or security, so any suggestions would be great. I just haven't gotten that far yet.

Thanks in advance

Ok I have gone back to the LOAD DATA INFILE but I am having issues with it working. Forgive me I have no solid reference to see this work correctly nor have I had any success getting it to work at all. I have never heard of fseek, or seen its use either. Based on what I read, I think the fseek may be what I am trying to accomplish. I just want to upload the data to the database. Do you have an example of fseek working?

I have tried the LOAD DATA INFILE but can't figure out where the error is

```
        if ($data[0]) {
    LOAD DATA INFILE '$file' INTO TABLE 'tabledata_01' (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5, COL6, COL7, COL8, COL9, COL10, COL11, COL12, COL13, COL14) VALUES
    $mysql_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tabledata_01 (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5, COL6, COL7, COL8, COL9, COL10, COL11, COL12, COL13, COL14) VALUES
            (
                '".addslashes($data[0])."',
                '".addslashes($data[1])."',
```

I have left both the old query below the LOAD DATA INFILE and attempted to see why or where I was getting the error. If you have an example of fseek, this may be a better solution, it certainly seems faster from what I read. Thank You

I was able to use The LOCAL because of my hosting, I used the @VAR to skip over unneeded fields/columns. Getting the use of MULTIPLE SET was a pain but I did figure it out.

```
$sqlstatement="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$temp' INTO TABLE 000_datetest FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (id, @sdate, name, @anotherdate, color, 1moredate) SET anotherdate = IF(LENGTH(@anotherdate)=7,STR_TO_DATE(@anotherdate,'%m/%d/%Y'),STR_TO_DATE(@anotherdate,'%m/%d/%y')), sdate = IF(LENGTH(@sdate)=7,STR_TO_DATE(@sdate,'%m/%d/%Y'),STR_TO_DATE(@sdate,'%m/%d/%y'))";
```

I could not figure out why the DATE format wouldn't work, so I changed it to varchar in the db and did not need the use of the SET I just hope it doesn't become an issue later when I I am running queries on the different dates and trying to calculate days in between.

here is the final:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['load']))
{
include '_inc/include.php';
$temp = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];
$sqlstatement="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$temp' INTO TABLE 000_datetest FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES(@COL1, @COL2, @COL3, @COL4, @COL5, @COL6, @COL7, @COL8, @COL9, @COL10, @COL11, @COL12, @COL13, listdate, closedate, contractdate, @COL17, status, statuschangedate, withdrawdate, canceldate, @COL22, @COL23, @COL24, listprice, soldprice, @COL27, @COL28, @COL29, @COL30, @COL31, @COL32, @COL33, @COL34, @COL35, @COL36, @COL37, @COL38, @COL39, @COL40, @COL41, @COL42, @COL43, @COL44, @COL45, @COL46, @COL47, @COL48, @COL49, @COL50, @COL51, gla, @COL53, @COL54, @COL55, built, @COL57, @COL58, @COL59, @COL60, @COL61, @COL62, @COL63, @COL64, @COL65, @COL66, @COL67, @COL68, @COL69, @COL70, @COL71, @COL72, @COL73, @COL74, @COL75, @COL76, @COL77, @COL78, @COL79, @COL80, @COL81, @COL82, owner, @COL84, @COL85, @COL86, @COL87, @COL88, @COL89, @COL90, @COL91, @COL92, @COL93, @COL94, fore, @COL96, @COL97, shortsale, @COL99, @COL100, @COL101, @COL102, @COL103, @COL104, @COL105, @COL106, @COL107, @COL108, @COL109, @COL110, @COL111, @COL112, @COL113, @COL114, @COL115, @COL116, @COL117, @COL118, @COL119, @COL120, @COL121, @COL122, @COL123, @COL124, @COL125, @features)";
mysql_query($sqlstatement) or die(mysql_error());
echo "It worked";
echo "<p><a href='upload-display2.php'>go to page</a></p>";
} 

?>

<form method="post" action="upload2.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="myfile" type="file" />
<input name="load" type="submit" value="submit" /></form>
```

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) ?

However, to skip the header lines you could use [fseek](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php).

Comment: I have tried to use LOAD DATA INFILE, as it is mentioned here a few times with several examples in other posts, but I could not get it to work. I do not know anything about fseek. The only other thing I found was fastercsv, but I am not using Ruby.

Comment: Ok after much reading and study sessions I was able to figure out LOAD DATA INFILE. My major problem was understanding why I needed to use LOCAL in there because of my host. Those of you following:

Comment: I was able to get Multiple SET usage and I was able to get all the fields skipped over I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop.

```
<?php

$row = 0;
while (($values = fgetcsv($handle)) !== false) {
    $row++;
    if ($row === 1) {
        $keys = $values;
        continue;
    }
    $row = array_combine($keys, $values);
}
```

This will use the first line as headers, and then combine the values of any subsequent rows to give you an associative array of heading name to cell value.

Comment: This is way cleaner than what I came up with. Thank you. I will try this